# Is it possible to assign to an html form input the value of a java String?

Tags: java, servlets

Is it possible to do something like this:

```
<form action="foo" method="get">
   <input type="hidden" name="ID" value="<% classInstance.getID(); %>">
</form>
```

?
Each time I try, the receiving Servlet does not display the Id of the classInstance.
How can I make this work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this instead :

```
<%= classInstance.getID() %>
```